# Theme Options: If There is No Input, Don't Display?

Tags: php, functions, theme-options

I have built a custom options panel which allows site owners to enter their social profiles.  I then use the second code to make the links appear in the theme.

**When no link is entered in the options panel, I would like there to be no link called on the page where the code is being called.  Currently, it provides me with a link to the homepage of my site.**

Take a look: http://themeforward.com/demo2/ - the green box is the facebook link, the purple is the google link

I know what you're thinking - why not just leave it the way it is?  Because, I'm styling each link with a background image rather than using normal text links... so if I just leave it this way we will still have an image showing up advertising a social site presence, but it won't be linked.  The styling can be found here: http://pastebin.com/m3PrBDae I think that may be affecting this.

In my functions

```
array( "name" => "Facebook Page",
    "desc" => "Enter your Facebook address. (Must include http://)",
    "id" => $shortname."_facebook",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => ""),

array( "name" => "Google Plus",
    "desc" => "Enter your Google Plus address. (Must include http://)",
    "id" => $shortname."_google_plus",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => ""),
```

How I call them

```
<a href="<?php echo get_option('to_facebook'); ?>"></a>
<a href="<?php echo get_option('to_google_plus'); ?>"></a>
```

Comment: What does `get_option('to_facebook')` return?

Comment: It returns a link that users must input in a text box in the options panel.

Comment: No, that's what your **markup** outputs. I'm asking what *specifically* does **`get_option( 'to_facebook' )`** return, *right now*, when you output it? Does it return null, false, blank, a string, etc.?

Comment: http://themeforward.com/demo2/ - the green box is the facebook code, the purple is the google... it returns a link to the homepage of my site

Comment: I apologize if I not asking my question clearly. I don't want to know what gets *rendered*, I want to know what *WordPress is returning* when you call `get_option()`. How about this: what do you get with `var_dump( get_option( 'to_facebook' ) )`?

Comment: http://themeforward.com/demo2/bool(false)

Comment: That means that `to_facebook` is returning `false` - in which case, the answers from both @ptriek and @Rutwick-Gangurde should work. I'll take a look at the pastebin code later, to see what might be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if get_option returns a value and if it is not blank, then output the links.
This should work for you:

```
<?php
if(get_option('to_facebook') && get_option('to_facebook') != '') {
     ?>
     <a href="<?php echo get_option('to_facebook'); ?>"></a>
    <?php     
}   
if(get_option('to_google_plus') && get_option('to_google_plus') != '') {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_option('to_google_plus'); ?>"></a>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: This is still outputting the links when it is blank.

Comment: Can you please show us how you implemented the solution?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/y1mA2q1q - at the top of my sidebar
my site - http://themeforward.com/demo2/

Comment: I should add there is styling being added to these links, and that may be creating the problem... but the styling is necessary http://pastebin.com/m3PrBDae

Comment: I modified the `if` statement, to include braces. It *shouldn't* make a difference here, but doesn't hurt to try. Otherwise, I can see nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Thanks Chip and thanks Rutwick!  It's working now, this was driving me crazy.

Comment: That's awesome and you're welcome! (Sorry for getting back late)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
if( get_option('to_facebook') ) { 
?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_option('to_facebook'); ?>"></a>
<?php
}
```

Comment: I'm getting syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: yes sorry, i was a bit quick - you need to add <?php and ?> on first and third line.
but - if @rutwicks code didn't work, I don't think my code would work either...

Comment: @ptriek Yes Exactly. There must be something else.